# TabError: Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indentation

I am new to python and I am trying to implement a dictionary but Im getting an error.

This is my code:

```
class Dictionary(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        self = {}

    def dict_keys(self):
        return [key for key in self.keys()]

    def set(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def items(self):
        return [(key, self[key]) for key in self.keys()]

    def values(self):
        return [self[key] for key in self.keys()]

    def len(self):
        return len(self.keys())

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except AttributeError:
            return default

    def has_key(self, name):
        return name in self.keys()
```

This is the error:

[image: This is the error]

I can't find the problem with it so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your using tabs *and* spaces? Pick one!

Comment: Note that your `__init__` here does nothing, as all you do is change what the *local variable* `self` refers to. This then immediately goes out of scope

Comment: Yep, I agree with @Zizouz212 . You've got tabs in the definitions of `dict_keys` and `has_key` and spaces everywhere else.

Comment: Is there some reason your re-engineering the [Python Dictionary structure](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? As everything in your class can just be achieved with a normal dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You used tabs AND spaces for indentation, which is not allowed. Configure your editor to use spaces when you press the tab button, e.g. 4 spaces. That way you can't accidentaly use tabs.